# How to get headers from a response in Angular 5

Tags: spring-security, angular6

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nW4z.jpg)

How I get this in my code?, I'm working with angular 6, and Spring security, but i need to get a token that is in the Headers of the response.

I do the post:

```
const httpoptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, body, Authorization ",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    })
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LogueoService {

    private censoURL = 'http://localhost:8080/login';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    inicio (username:string,password:string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.censoURL, {username, password }, httpoptions );
    }
}
```

Comment: From server side you need to allow expose header in response like this. `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");`

Comment: Tnx, it works :3